# Bash - Cat a file that doesn't exist for use in project

Tags: bash

Learning bash and am looking for the right way to get variables from a file, if it exists.

Here is my solution so far.. but I am unsure if I am doing this the correct way.

```
#!/bin/bash

files_in_folder=$(ls)
if [ files_in_folder = *".bicycle"* ];
then
  project_vars=$(cat ./.bicycle)
fi

cycle_api_key=$(echo $project_vars | jq -r '.cycle_api_key')
project_location=$(echo $project_vars | jq -r '.project_location')
project_name=$(echo $project_vars | jq -r '.project_name')
project_tag=$(echo $project_vars | jq -r '.project_tag')
image_to_push="$project_name:$project_tag"
location_and_image_to_push="$project_location/$project_name:$project_tag"
cycle_hub_id=$(echo $project_vars | jq -r '.cycle_hub_id')
container_to_push_to=$(echo $project_vars | jq -r '.container_id')
private_registry_input=$(echo $project_vars | jq -r '.private_registry_input')
```

I initially did not have the if statement at the top... just:

`project_vars=$(cat ./.bicycle)`

This made the program print:

`cat: ./.bicycle: No such file or directory`

I know that by adding this if statement, this warning went away... but I am unsure if I am importing the file the correct way. Should I be sourcing it?

The file is always called `.bicycle` and it only contains a json object.

Thanks for your help!

Based on an answer and some coments below, is my current updated code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -r .bicycle; then 
  project_vars=$(cat ./.bicycle) || exit
fi

eval "$(jq -r '
  "cycle_hub_id=\(.cycle_hub_id|@sh);
  project_location=\(.project_location|@sh);
  project_name=\(.project_name|@sh);
  project_tag=\(.project_tag|@sh);
  cycle_hub_id=\(.cycle_hub_id|@sh);
  container_to_push_to=\(.container_id|@sh);
  private_registry_input=\(.private_registry_input|@sh)"
  ' <<< "$project_vars")"

location_and_image_to_push=""$project_location"/"$project_name":"$project_tag""
image_to_push=""$project_name":"$project_tag""
```

Comment: To see if a file exists, use `test -e`.

Comment: If you're going to use `echo`, you should use quotes: `echo "$project_vars"`.

Comment: Note that it would be much more efficient to just run `jq` _once_ and have that one run extract all the variables you need.

Comment: Charles - Wow. I am going to try this.

Comment: I am thinking of how to run this once... Would I run this on my variable, $project_vars?

Comment: `project_vars='{"cycle_hub_id": "hubA", "project_location": "luna"}';
eval "$(jq -r '"cycle_hub_id=\(.cycle_hub_id|@sh); project_location=\(.project_location|@sh)"' <<<"$project_vars")"`

Comment: BTW, don't use `ls` in scripts; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: That code looks great. I can certainly expand on it. I'll need to look up the syntax to write it - indents and spaces and such, which I know cant be done here in a comment. Thanks for this!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  -- This works great so far! -- I updated the last portion of my question to include your update... Now just to figure out syntax. -- I also excluded the first part of your comment code, "project_vars='{"cycle_hub_id": "hubA".....", as I did not want to have any set variables if the user has not set them yet. Thanks again for the guidence!

Comment: That's doable, but it really should be its own question; each question should be about exactly one thing. (I'd also suggest moving details on how you applied suggested solutions into an answer if you think it adds something to the discussion, rather than including it as part of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to check if a file exists is with `test -e`:

```
if test -e .bicycle; then 
        project_vars=$(cat ./.bicycle)
fi
```

Just because the file exists, however, does not mean it is readable, so you may want `test -r .bicycle`.

However, just because it exists and is readable does not mean that it is well formatted json, so you may want to validate it.  But it's probably sufficient to do:

```
project_vars=$(cat ./.bicycle) || exit
```

If you want to continue processing when the file does not exist (so project_vars is allowed to be the empty string, use the `|| exit` suffix inside the body of `if test -e .bicycle`.

Comment: This is awesome. I'll put everything you said into action here. I am trying to up my bash best practices as they are growing, but currently are low. Everything you have said is very helpful.  -- Thanks for providing the information about the validation of json data. My program creates the json data in another function, but I never considered if a user tries to edit it (like I would). This will be a great addition to the code.  I'll try this out and let you know how it works! Thank You!

Comment: This is working as you explained - I provided an updated code above if you want to see. 

The code above is working if the file exists or doesn't exist, which is what I was hoping for. 

I also quoted all the variables - I'll be testing this out next to see if it changes anything down the pipe. 

Thanks so much for taking your time - I appreciate the help.